# What is an overview of secondary school astronomy textbooks for students who have taken some calculus?

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, education

I teach mathematics at the secondary level. This year my students have founded an astronomy club. Most have finished two semesters of "college-level" calculus and are familiar with the derivative, proper and improper integrals, convergence of series, and (some) linear differential equations. They have also taken algebra-based physics and are comfortable with vector arithmetic, though they have not had significant instruction in multivariable calculus. Ideally, many of the students will take that course concurrently with their club activities, though I anticipate that some younger students will not (though it's okay if some of the arguments are over the younger heads as long as the content keeps them engaged). They have not had any instruction in astronomy, space science, or astrophysics.

Some topics I'm interested in discussing are:

- mechanics of the solar system
- Newton's laws & Kepler's laws
- origin of the solar system
- planetary phenomenon (weather, volcanism, auroras, etc)
- solar system exploration
- comets, asteroids, and transneptunian objects
- hypothetical interstellar exploration
- life cycles of stars
- stellar phenomenon (sunspots, flares, magnetic properties, flares, and violent events)
- electromagnetic radiation
- black body radiation
- light and telescopes
- origin of the galaxies
- galactic structure and evolution
- large scale structure of the universe
- Doppler effect
- Hubble's law

It's important to remember that these are not college students, and this is not a class. Students may solve interesting problems in meetings but will not have any assigned work besides recommended readings.

What is an overview of astrophysics texts that are appropriate for use as the club's references? Included titles might cover some or all of the topics above- I am open to using a small number of books instead of just one as long as they are inexpensive to obtain. A web or print resource that lists and reviews such textbooks would also be enormously helpful.

Comment: That is a tight schedule, especially since one could spend between an entire lecture and an entire course on individual topics. Most of them can only be discussed on a very superficial level given the limited exposure of your students to basic physics and, am I assuming this correctly, your lack of personal experience with the topic? Then there is the name of the club... "astronomy" is an experimental discipline that happens at night in the dark using telescopes and similar instruments and that requires an entirely different set of skills than astrophysics. Is there _any_ observation involved?

Comment: On a second note... and before a solar astronomer comes after me with a big club (and righteously so!)... one can do absolutely marvelous astronomical observations during the daytime... and not just on the sun or during an eclipse. One of my personal favorites is finding Venus with my own eyes during the day.

Comment: @CuriousOne I plan on discussing these topics in a multi-year cycle. I have access to some very good night-sky video lectures and we host observations and attend some hosted by a local astronomical society- that aspect has already lifted off, but the kids are adventurous (and very bright) and are interested in physics, and always want to discuss astrophysics at our weekly day-time meetings. I am not an astronomer but have published in a related field. I would like to have a reference that I can direct them to or compose some lectures from at their request.

Comment: Personally, and this is really just my preference, I would try to focus more on observations and general knowledge about the solar system and the universe than on hard physics topics. While I understand that every student wants to know about black holes or how we know the age of the universe, if they can't look up in the sky and tell that Jupiter and Mars are overhead, something is missing. Maybe your students know those things, already, maybe they have seen the sky trough a telescope... but if they haven't, that's where the "Ahhhh!" is, not in the black body radiation formula.

Comment: @CuriousOne I can appreciate that.